# Difference between [] and $ in R

Tags: r

What to know the difference between [] and $ in column selection in R!!!!

e.g.

```
Excel$Column_name
Excel[1]
```

How both commend work?
I some cases one of the commend doesn't execute or do what we want.
Just want know the difference b/w these cases!!

Comment: [$] is `[[]]` and returns a vector, `[]` returns a `list`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169456/2994949